# Remove unnecessary symbols in the data in R

Tags: r, dataframe, gsub

That's my dataset

```
1.abc
2.def
3.2354
4.. $.?,
```

How can I delete those obs in which only digits, in which only symbols like point, comma ..., well, in which any symbols and digits(1#5??%).And words in the text where less than two letters

Comment: Try `df1$v1[nchar(gsub("[^[:alpha:]]+", "", df1$v1))>2]` or `stringr::str_count(df1$v1, "[a-z]")> 2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `str_count` to count the number of characters and subset the dataset

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    filter(str_count(v1, "[[:alpha:]]") > 2)
```

---

Or with `gsub` to remove any character that is not a letter and count the number of characters with `nchar` to create a logical index for subsetting

```
subset(df1, nchar(gsub("[^[:alpha:]]+", "", v1))>2)
#    v1
#1 1.abc
#2 2.def
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(v1 = c("1.abc", "2.def", "3.2354", "4.. $.?,")), 
.Names = "v1", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```